# Communicate 2 desktop program with modbus on same pc

Tags: modbus, plc

There are two program on my pc. First one is a PLC program and the second one is a robot program. I can simulate and run the programs seperately. On the real world the robot and plc communicate with modbus. But I want to go on my works at home.

How can I communicate two programs with modbus on the same pc?

Answer (score 0):

Do they both support serial (Modbus/RTU) or Ethernet (Modbus/TCP)?

If it's serial, you will need two COM ports, one Mastering out COM1 and the other being a Slave on COM2 (or whatever 2 serial ports are on your PC).

If it's Ethernet, then set up one to master and one to be the slave on LocalPort 127.0.0.1 and it should just work.

If they both support both serial and Ethernet, go with Ethernet, because I doubt your PC has two COM ports.